# Extract data from a span with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract data from a span with BeautifulSoup from two differents way

```
import requests
import bs4

url ='https://www.futbin.com/19/player/477/Jordan%20Henderson/'
page = requests.get(url).content
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')



price1 = soup.find("div", {"class": "bin_price lbin"}).span.contents
price2 = soup.select('#ps-lowest-1')


print(price1)
print(price2)
```

It gave me two results

```
[u'\n', <span id="ps-lowest-1">-</span>, u'\n']
[<span id="ps-lowest-1">-</span>]
[Finished in 1.0s]
```

Now I would like to extract data (the price) from this span and I can't
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Tip: Open developer toos and check which resources the page is requesting. A `XHR` request is loading the content to the page, parse it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you wanted is come from XHR or Ajax, first you need to extract the ID then use it for getting JSON content.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ='https://www.futbin.com/19/player/477/Jordan%20Henderson/'
page = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

playerId = soup.find(id="page-info")['data-baseid'] # 183711

jsonURL = url ='https://www.futbin.com/19/playerPrices?player=' + playerId
jsonObj = requests.get(url).json()
# print(jsonObj)

psLowestPrice = jsonObj[playerId]['prices']['ps']['LCPrice']
print(psLowestPrice)
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual prices are not present in the HTML you get inside the `page` variable. *Prices are loaded dynamically via a separate request in your browser*.

You could simulate that request in your code as well:

```
from pprint import pprint
import requests

url ='https://www.futbin.com/19/playerPrices?player=183711'
page = requests.get(url).json()

pprint(page)
```

Would print:

```
{u'183711': {u'prices': {u'pc': {u'LCPrice': u'1,500',
                                 u'LCPrice2': u'1,500',
                                 u'LCPrice3': u'1,500',
                                 u'LCPrice4': u'1,500',
                                 u'LCPrice5': u'1,500',
                                 u'MaxPrice': u'10,000',
                                 u'MinPrice': u'700',
                                 u'PRP': u'8',
                                 u'updated': u'49 mins ago'},
                         u'ps': {u'LCPrice': u'1,300',
                                 u'LCPrice2': u'1,300',
                                 u'LCPrice3': u'1,300',
                                 u'LCPrice4': u'1,300',
                                 u'LCPrice5': u'1,300',
                                 u'MaxPrice': u'10,000',
                                 u'MinPrice': u'700',
                                 u'PRP': u'6',
                                 u'updated': u'25 mins ago'},
                         u'xbox': {u'LCPrice': u'1,500',
                                   u'LCPrice2': u'1,500',
                                   u'LCPrice3': u'1,600',
                                   u'LCPrice4': u'1,600',
                                   u'LCPrice5': u'1,600',
                                   u'MaxPrice': u'10,000',
                                   u'MinPrice': u'700',
                                   u'PRP': u'8',
                                   u'updated': u'30 mins ago'}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

bs4 select gives you a list of matched tags.
Following your example, what about doing:

```
price1 = soup.find("div", {"class": "bin_price lbin"}).span.contents
price2 = soup.select('#ps-lowest-1')
```

Access the text inside the first element in the list:

```
print(price2[0].text)
```

Or check all:

```
for elem in price2:
  print(elem.text)
```